# Java For Loop, why J < I?

Tags: java, for-loop

Can someone please explain to me why `j < i` in the loop.

```
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
    boolean isPrime = true;

    //check to see if the number is prime
    for(int j=2; j < i ; j++){
        if(i % j == 0){
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }

    // print the number
    if(isPrime)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

As `i` goes into the second loop isn't `i==1`?

Comment: Yes, for the first time, but not after that.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: technicaly, this will work, if i==1 the second loop will not be entered at all because j<i is never met. However, mathematically this code has a huge potential to be optimized, for example, it is sufficient to check only up to sqrt(i)+1.

Comment: I disagree with Juhana. The second loop will never be executed with i == 1

Comment: @JMullen That's what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As i goes into the second loop isn't i==1?

The answer to this is no.

A for-loop's conditions are basically a boolean. Your nested for-loop you have

`for(int j=2; j < i ; j++)`

This means that for this for-loop to execute, j MUST be < i.

If you put a break point on this line and step through it in your debugger, this will become much more obvious to you.

So what I am trying to say is no, when `i==1`, it is impossible for the second for-loop to execute, because `j<i` is `false`.

So, starting from the very beginning of your code, you have

```
for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
    boolean isPrime = true;

    //check to see if the number is prime
    for(int j=2; j < i ; j++){
        if(i % j == 0){
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }

    // print the number
    if(isPrime)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Running from the beginning you will have `i=1`. `isPrime` will be set equal to `true`, and then it will check to see if the parameters of your second for-loop are met.

```
for(int j=2; j < i ; j++)
```

`j < i` is `false`, so the for-loop will not execute. The code will skip over it and go to your if statement `if(isPrime)`

Next iteration you will have `i=2`, the second for-loop will be checked, and seeing that `j<i` holding values of `2 < 2` is `false`, the loop will be skipped again.

The third iteration you will have `i=3`. The inner loop will be checked for `j<i` holding the values of `2 < 3` which is `TRUE` this time, so the loop will finally execute.

Hopefully this makes sense. Like I mentioned before, if it is still unclear to you, run it through your debugger and it should become clear.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for prime numbers, between 1 to 100.
For each number, i (that goes from 1 to 100), you want to check if there is a *smaller* number (j) who divide it.
Smaller number means that j < i.

As for the first iteration of the loop, i = 1, so the inner loop won't be executed, and that ok because 1 is prime - you don't need to check if it's divided by smaller numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Optimisation, because if `j > i` <=> `i % j == i`, and never `== 0`.